# what is bus error ? when it comes?

Tags: iphone

in my application bus error is showing and application crash ..i want to know when this error comes . what mean by bus error ?

in my application page on diffrent id i have to calling libxml parsing . in many times calling, ones it crash .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Bus_error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As getluky states in [his answer on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7631/what-is-a-sigbus-in-unity-iphone-and-why-does-it-h.html):

> I've seen SIGBUS often occur on NULL reference exceptions that occur
>   at runtime. They are usually fairly straightforward to track down via
>   the XCode debugger - hit the Continue button a couple times while
>   monitoring the XCode debug console output. It usually will give a hint
>   as to what file and line number the null reference was in.
>
> Not sure why recreating the XCode project would fix it - it's usually
>   an issue that recurs unless I can fix the underlying problem

Comment: SIGBUS is the signal sent to a process when it causes a bus error.A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault), bus error or access violation is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address. It occurs when the hardware notifies an operating system about a memory access violation

Comment: You plagiarized this answer from getluky on Unity Answers. I've added proper citation in your answer here, but taking credit for the work of others is not tolerated here, so do not copy the words of others without proper credit.

Answer (score 1):

Usually bus error occurs when you are trying to access a deallocated object. Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/) to check which object get released.

Comment: That is actually wrong. When you try to access a deallocated object you may be accessing memory you don't own. This will result in a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) and not a bus error (SIGBUS).